# Emulating Node/Express Routes in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, altorouter

I have been trying to emulate how nodejs/express work with their routes. I am forwarding all traffic to `index.php` to process routes (using [AltoRouter](http://altorouter.com/)).

My file struture is something like this:

```
-/
--public/
  |- assets
  |- ...
--routes/
  |- route.php
  |- ...
--index.php
```

Take these urls for instance (all should return/redirect 404):

`http://testsite.com/routes`

`http://testsite.com/routes/route.php`

`http://testsite.com/somefile.php`

However only assets should be directly accessible like so (I dont want to include `/public/`:

`http://testsite.com/assets/image.png`

`http://testsite.com/assets/styles/style.css`

This is what I have so far:

```
# Make sure mod_rewrite is on
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # This should allow us to get our assets and keep them public
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|css|js|swf)$ /public/$1.$2 [L,NC]

    # Forward other traffic to index.php
    RewriteRule ^.+$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

One issue i've come accross is going: `http://testsite.com/routes`produces:
[image]

**I Guess my main question is anything that isnt in public shouldnt be accessable (not sure if .htacces is the way to go or not)**

Comment: In most cases, proper frameworks will have you move your .htaccess and index.php files to the /public folder, and then map your domain's webroot to /public. This way, your routes folder - and anything else that can be associated with your back-end logic - stays out of webroot and becomes inaccessible to directory traversal.

Comment: @maiorano84 If I don't have access to your host configuration, could I not map it myself?

Comment: Hmmmmm, if you don't have server access to the Apache/NGINX configuration, that complicates things. Do you have access to a server control panel like cPanel or Plesk?

Comment: @maiorano84 I do.

Comment: Then that's where you can set those configurations. Personally, I would adjust the domain to point to your /public folder as the root. Once there, your public folder's index.php file can bootstrap the application and handle everything from there. [Take a look at how Laravel does it](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/index.php) for some ideas. [Here's their .htaccess file](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess) to show you how simple it can be.

Comment: @maiorano84 Could i not just forward all traffic (other than that to a specific file in the public folder) to index.php?

Comment: @maiorano84 these "proper" frameworks usually also allow direct access to every file and directory in the web root because of `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}` checks, which is how remote shells and other malicious scripts get triggered.

Comment: @Walf That's adorable. No, if you're looking at any modern framework, the only server-side script that's made accessible in Webroot or above is the index file. Nothing else. Do your research.

Comment: Also, if Wordpress is the only framework/CMS you know how to use, you should consider expanding your horizons a bit.

Comment: @maiorano84 The only server-side script that *you* make available is in the public directory, but as soon as someone manages to upload a malicious script, you're owned. [Look at Laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess),  no attempt at preventing any script execution, there.  What's turdpress got to do with anything? It's not a framework and I've only used it at work out obligation, not choice. Being patronizing doesn't strengthen your position, it just makes you look like an idiot.

Comment: @maiorano84 I think Walf is correct here. The Question wasnt about what proper frameworks do. I simple wanted to know a solution to my exact issue. If I wanted to use a framework I would. Also, please note there are more than one ways to do things.

Comment: @maiorano84 Also, you shooting your mouth off at someone who can answer the question in ~3 lines is a bit silly when your response is "Hmmmmm, if you don't have server access to the Apache/NGINX configuration, that complicates things."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to bury your files above web root if you use the right rules. Private files can easily be made inaccessible.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    # transform assets URLs to correct path, and proceed to next rule
    # checking existence in RewriteConds is useless here since public URLs are not 1:1 physical paths
    RewriteRule ^assets/.+ public/$0 [NS,DPI]
    # send *all* URLs to index.php except those that point to an asset file that exists
    RewriteCond $1 !=public/assets/ [OR]
    # change the slash in next condition to your sub-directory if not serving from the web root, e.g. %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/project/root/$0
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$0 !-f
    RewriteRule ^((?:[^/]+/){2})?.+ index.php [NS,END]
</IfModule>
```