# Routing everything to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need my htaccess file to redirect all URI calls to my index.php in my /public folder.

This means, that I don't want domain.com/ to access "root", but to redirect to my /public folder.

I actually have it working in some way now with the following:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^$    public/    [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

But my problem is, that I can access ALL files in the /public folder with both `domain.com/$1` and `domain.com/public/$1`

Can I avoid that in any way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emulating Node/Express Routes in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40442864/emulating-node-express-routes-in-htaccess)

Comment: If you just rewrite everything to that dir, then visiting `/public/` will actually serve `/public/public/` which should 404.